# Sqlite select statement inside another select statement

Tags: android, sql-order-by, android-sqlite, sql

I have created an sqlite database for an android project. I want to order a select statement according to another select statement result.

I have two table like this;

**Table A:**

[A_ID] [Name] **[B_ID]**

**Table B:**

**[B_ID]** [B_Detail]

Now, I can select TableA, but I couldn't order it according to  B_Detail.

I have tried to write rawQuery, but I didn't accomplish it.

**Edit:**

I solved problem with this statement;

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT Table_A.* FROM Table_A JOIN Table_B USING (B_ID) ORDER BY Table_B.B_Detail]", null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

database.rawQuery("SELECT Table_A.* FROM Table_A JOIN Table_B USING (B_ID) ORDER BY Table_B.B_Detail]", null);

Answer (score 0):

You can execute nested query like

```
String sql="Select A_ID, Name, B_ID from Table A where B_ID IN (Select B_ID from Table_B)";
db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

SELECT [A_ID],[Name],[B_ID] FROM TableA
  WHERE [B_ID] in(SELECT [B_ID] FROM [B_Detail])